# R: Shaded area between multiple sets of data

Tags: r

I'd like to achieve the following effect in R:
[image: Three shaded areas bounded by 6 lines]

I got 6 sets set of data in the following form:

- Series 1:

  - a_1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
  - a_2 <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
- Series 2:

  - b_1 <- c(2,6,4,7,4,7,3,5,8,5,4)
  - b_2 <- c(2,3,4,4,5,6,2,4,6,7,3)
- Series 3:

  - c_1 <- c(8,7,6,5,4,3)
  - c_2 <- c(6,5,4,3,2,1)

I'd like to smooth the lines and color the areas in between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just deleted my answer given a minute before, as I realized you do not want to smooth a line around points, but just want to show areas between them, and the points are counted before visualization.

This way plotting could be very easy with [geom_ribbon](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_ribbon.html) from [ggplot2 package](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2).

For example:

```
# load package
library(ggplot2)
# generate some data
huron <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972,level = as.vector(LakeHuron)) 
huron$level2 <- huron$level+runif(nrow(huron))*10-5
# plot
h <-ggplot(huron, aes(x=year))
h + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-1, ymax=level+1)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level2-1, ymax=level2+1), color="red",  fill="red")
```

[image]

Comment: And if you do not like the grey background, add `+ theme_bw()` at the end of last command.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure this out and read about so I can use it on my data sets, this however, seems exactly what I'm looking fo