# r - ggplot2 - create a shaded region between two geom_abline layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801571/ggplot2-shade-area-above-line) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691980/r-shaded-area-between-multiple-sets-of-data) regarding the use of shaded areas in ggplot2, but I don't think any exactly answer my question. I have two slopes for lines across a number of conditions, and I would like to shade the region between them. Here is example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(cond1=c("a","a","b","b"),
              cond2=c("c","d","c","d"),
              x=c(1,5),
              y=c(1,5),
              sl=c(1,1.2,0.9,1.1),
              int=c(0,0.1,0.1,0),
              slopeU=c(1.1,1.3,1.2,1.2),
              slopeL=c(.9,1,0.7,1))
```

Here, `sl` is the mean slope parameter from a separate fitting procedure, and `slopeU` and `slopeL` represent upper and lower confidence regions on the slope estimate in each condition. The intercepts are constrained to be the same. The following code plots the best fitting lines for each condition using some faceting:

```
p <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=cond1))
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ cond2)
p <- p + geom_blank()
p <- p + geom_abline(aes(intercept=int,slope=sl,colour=cond1),data=dat)
p
```

I would like to add the lines defined by `intercept=int, slope=slopeU` and `intercept=int, slope=slopeL` to the plot and shade the region between them (e.g. at `alpha=.5` in the corresponding cond1 colour).

I recognise that with a little manipulation I could create a data frame specifying values of these lines for at least two x values, then plot the corresponding geom_ribbon or geom_polygon to create the shaded region, however I would like to find a more elegant solution. Or is manually specifying some coordinates from the slopes and intercepts the only way? How would I best create the required data frame (which will need to have more rows than the original frame to account for all combinations of conditions and x,y pairs).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I think that creating the data frames and using `geom_ribbon` *is* the elegant solution, but obviously opinions will differ on that score.

But if you take full advantage of **plyr** and **ggplot** things can get pretty slick. Since your slopes and intercepts are all nicely stored in a dataframe anyway, we can use **plyr** and a custom function to do all the work:

```
dat <- data.frame(cond1=c("a","a","b","b"),
          cond2=c("c","d","c","d"),
          x=c(1,5),
          y=c(1,5),
          sl=c(1,1.2,0.9,1.1),
          int=c(0,0.1,0.1,0),
          slopeU=c(1.1,1.3,1.2,1.2),
          slopeL=c(.9,1,0.7,1))

genRibbon <- function(param,xrng){
    #xrng is a vector of min/max x vals in original data
    r <- abs(diff(xrng))
    #adj for plot region expansion
    x <- seq(xrng[1] - 0.05*r,xrng[2] + 0.05*r,length.out = 3)
    #create data frame
    res <- data.frame(cond1 = param$cond1,
                      cond2 = param$cond2,
                      x = x,
                      y = param$int + param$sl * x,
                      ymin = param$int + param$slopeL * x,
                      ymax = param$int + param$slopeU * x)
    #Toss the min/max x vals just to be safe; needed them 
    # only to get the corresponding y vals
    res$x[which.min(res$x)] <- -Inf
    res$x[which.max(res$x)] <- Inf
    #Return the correspondinng geom_ribbon
    geom_ribbon(data = res,aes(x = x,y=y, ymin = ymin,ymax = ymax,
                               fill = cond1,colour = NULL),
                alpha = 0.5)
}

ribs <- dlply(dat,.(cond1,cond2),genRibbon,xrng = c(1,5))
```

The extra slick thing here is that I'm discarding the generated data frames completely and just returning a list of `geom_ribbon` objects. Then they can simply be added to our plot:

```
p + ribs + 
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.1)))
```

I overrode the `alpha` aesthetic in the legend because the first time around you couldn't see the diagonal lines in the legend.

[image]

I'll warn you that the last line there that generates the plots also throws a lot of warnings about invalid factor levels, and I'm honestly not sure why. But the plot looks ok.

Comment: So that basically works with my applied problem, but I can't get the colours on the shaded regions to cond1, even by running your solution exactly. The filled ribbon regions are gray (at alpha = .5) but also have thin solid line borders . Where am I going wrong? Could this be a ggplot2 version difference? I'm on 0.9.0. The ggplot command I'm using is as in the original post, with `p + ribs + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.1)))` pasted below.

Comment: @waldog Sorry, just missed a bit when copy+pasting my code. You just have to add `fill = cond1` in `aes()` either in the top level `ggplot()` call, or in the `geom_ribbon` call inside the function. I'll edit momentarily...

Comment: Ah, of course. I was trying all kinds of colour specifications, forgetting that it would of course be a Fill. Thanks.